# Unknown keywords in keepalived.conf

Tags: server, configuration

Getting the following message when checking status of keepalived :

```
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- 1 Keepalived[1727]: (Line 3) Unknown keyword 'interface'
Feb 07 17:32:12 s   Keepalived[1727]: (Line 4) Unknown keyword 'vitual_router_id'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: (Line 5) Unknown keyword 'priority'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st1 Keepalived[1727]: (Line 6) Unknown keyword 'advert_int_1'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: (Line 7) Unknown keyword 'virtual'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: (Line 7) Unexpected '{' - ignoring
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: (Line 8) Unknown keyword '10.10.XXX.XX/24'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: (Line 9) Unknown keyword '}'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: (Line 10) Unknown keyword '}'
Feb 07 17:32:12 st- Keepalived[1727]: Warning - keepalived has no configuration to run
```

keepalived.conf looks like this :

```
vrrp_intance stnexus1 {
   state BACKUP
   interface ens192
   vitual_router_id 102
   priority 200
   advert_int_1
   virtual ipaddress {
      10.10.XXX.XX/24
   }
}
```

Appreciate you help thank you

Comment: What version and type of Ubuntu? Server or Desktop or Core?

Comment: Thank you for your response .... I rebuilt the server and all ok now.... Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The keyword vrrp_instance is misspelled as vrrp_intance instead. This is causing keepalived to ignore the entire block because it does not recognize the name.